# Counting Lattice Point and a failure of Strichartz estimate on periodic domain

Tags: elementary-number-theory, partial-differential-equations, integer-lattices

My question comes from the expression (4.48) of the [textbook of Linares and Ponce](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4939-2181-2) which states that the direct imitation of Strichartz estimate for $(t,x) \in [0,2\pi]^2$ is not true.

I don't know how to show that counterexample:

> There is a constant $c>0$ such that for all large enough integers $N$, $\| \sum_{k=1}^N e^{i (k^2 t + kx)}\|^6_{L^6_{t,x}} \geq c N^3 \log N$.

A direct computation shows that this problem is equivalent to show the following problem of counting lattice point has a lower bound $c N^3 \log N$:

> $ \#\{(k_1,j_1,k_2,j_2,k_3,j_3) \in \mathbb{N}^6_{\leq N}: k_1-j_1+k_2-j_2+k_3-j_3 = k_1^2 - j_1^2 + k_2^2 - j_2^2 + k_3^2 - j_3^2 = 0 \} \geq cN^3 \log N $.

**My attempt**

For each fixed $(j_1,j_2,j_3)$ (maybe each $j_i \geq N/2$ is needed),

I conjecture that the number of lattice points on intersection of the sphere $k_1^2+k_2^2+k_3^2 = j_1^2 + j_2^2+ j_3^2$ and the plane $k_1+k_2+k_3 = j_1 + j_2+ j_3$ is greater than some thing of order $\log N$. But I don't know how to show this.

Many thanks for any discussion or idea!

Comment: Here's an idea.  Fix any $j_2,k_2,j_3,k_3$: then we get equations $k_1-j_1 = A$ and $k_1^2-j_1^2 = B$.  Supposing that $A \ne 0$, this yields a unique rational value for $j_1,k_1$: it will be an integer provided that $A \mid B$ and that $B/A$ has the same parity as $A$ (we could restrict the parity of $j_2,\ldots$ to ensure this latter condition).  Now unfix $j_2,\ldots$ and consider all the values of $B$ for a fixed $A$: we might hope to show that these are distributed well enough mod $A$ that about $1/A$ satisfy the divisibility criterion, so the $\log N$ comes from a harmonic series.

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks! I try to use your idea to write down a proof. But I can't. Can you explain more details?

Comment: Well, it's just an idea, I haven't figured out how to turn it into a proof but I can try to flesh it out into a partial answer.  Out of curiosity is there a reference given for this lower bound?

Comment: Thanks for your mention. I do some survey on the internet and have found a satisfactory proof for the $L^6$ inequality. I post an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the above $L^6$ inequality is answered in the [notes](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~toh/Files/WeylSum.pdf) of Tadairo Oh (maybe earlier in a [classical paper](http://math.mit.edu/classes/18.158/bourgain-restriction.pdf) of Bouragin ) by a method of computing the Weyl sum $\sum_{n =1}^N e^{i (nx + n^2 t)}$ (sometimes called the exponential sum).

So we can prove that inequality without solving the counting lattice problem I post.

Conversely, I learn that some counting lattice problem can be solved by using suitable Weyl sum.